# Why is my VBA not finding functions in a C++ DLL?

Tags: c++, vba, dll, dllimport

I needed to write a DLL in C++ containing a couple of functions that I'd be later using in VBA.

The .h file I've written looks like this (though, I admit I have been copying from some examples on the internet since I am **very** new to C++, and I'm not sure I *need* all this stuff):

```
 // FieldTrans.h

#ifndef FIELDTRANS
#ifdef _WIN32
#ifdef BUILD_DLL
#define FIELDTRANS_FUNC __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define FIELDTRANS_FUNC __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#define FIELDTRANS_FUNC
#else
#define FIELDTRANS_FUNC __attribute__ ((visibility("default"))) type
#endif

// Returns the interpolated field matrix: 180° x 360° with Res step
FIELDTRANS_FUNC double ShannonInterp(double* Matrix, double Res, double DeltaTheta, double DeltaPhi);
// Returns the normalized cardinal sinus coefficient
FIELDTRANS_FUNC double SpecialLog(double x);
#endif
```

While the .cpp file contains the actual definition of those functions:

```
// FieldTrans.cpp

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "FieldTrans.h"
#include <array>            // for counting elements of an array
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES   // for M_PI 
#include <math.h>           // for M_PI and Log10  

using namespace std;

double SinC(double x)
{
    if (x == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return sin(M_PI * x) / (M_PI * x);
    }
}

double ShannonInterp(double *Matrix[], double Res, double DeltaTheta, double DeltaPhi)
{
    int k, l, m, n;
    double iRes, jRes;
    double ThetaSinC, PhiSinC;
    int MatrixHeigth = sizeof(Matrix) / sizeof(Matrix[0]), MatrixWidth = sizeof(Matrix[0]) / sizeof(Matrix);
    int Height = 180 / Res, Width = 360 / Res;
    double *Interpolated = new double[Height * Width];
    k = 0;
    m = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < Height; i++)
    {
        iRes = i * Res;
        do
        {
            k = k + 1;
            m = k + 1;
        } while (iRes > (k + 1) * DeltaTheta);
        if (m > MatrixHeigth)
        {
            m = MatrixHeigth - 1;
        }
        ThetaSinC = SinC((iRes - k * DeltaTheta) / DeltaTheta);
        l = 0;
        n = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < Width; j++)
        {
            jRes = j * Res;
            do
            {
                l = l + 1;
                n = l + 1;
            } while (jRes > (l + 1) * DeltaPhi);
            if (n > MatrixWidth)
            {
                n = 0;
            }
            PhiSinC = SinC((jRes - l * DeltaPhi) / DeltaPhi);
            Interpolated[i * Width + j] = Matrix[k][l] * ThetaSinC * PhiSinC + Matrix[k][n] * ThetaSinC * (1 - PhiSinC) + Matrix[m][l] * (1 - ThetaSinC) * PhiSinC + Matrix[m][n] * (1 - ThetaSinC) * (1 - PhiSinC);
        }
    }
    return *Interpolated;
}
```

I'm quite positive that the .cpp part works just fine.
I created a DLL by using Visual Studio and using "Project"-"Project properties"-"C/C++"-"Code generation" by modifying one of the options to "Multithreaded-DLL (/MD)".
After the DLL had been created, I wrote the following code in my VBA program:

```
Private Declare Function Shannonize Lib "C:\Users\daquino\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\FieldTrans\Release\FieldTrans.dll" Alias _
                        "ShannonInterp" (ByRef Matrix() As Double, ByVal Res As Double, ByVal DeltaTheta As Double, ByVal DeltaPhi As Double) As Double
```

But it doesn't work, since when I use the function, it says that it cannot be found in the module. I'm using the function like this:

```
InterpCo = Shannonize(AmplCo, Resolution, 181 / (PointsTheta+1), 361 / (PointsPhi+1))
```

Provided `AmplCo` is a 2D-array of Double, and the others inputs are Integer.

Could you please help me understand what's wrong?

EDIT: if I try to insert a reference to the .dll from my VBA program, it says "bad reference".

Comment: Inspect the DLL's exports with dumpbin or Dependency Walker.

Comment: There is a lot wrong.  The C++ compiler decorates the name of the function to support overloading, you'd have to turn that off with `extern "C"`.  The calling convention is wrong, you have to use `__stdcall`.  VBA expects to marshal arrays as a `SAFEARRAY`.  You can't add a reference, this is not a COM server and Declare is all you got.  Make small steps to get there, don't try to do this all in one giant gulp or you'll inevitably get stuck.  There are an enormous number of web pages that show how to do this.

Comment: I've been reading all sorts of stuff for 2 days, and yes, while I agree that I shouldn't gulp the whole thing in a single time, I'm still *expected* to do it. Maybe I'm dumb, but I found no example on something similar to what I need to do here. Even `extern` doesn't work the way it's supposed to, if I use it in the header *and* in che cpp file as @VTT points out

Comment: It takes time. Follow Hans advice. Otherwise you will never succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like names of the C++ functions that you are exporting from dll have been mangled. Unlike C, C++ functions can be overloaded (same name but different arguments), can dwell in namespaces, etc. so names of exported functions will also include some extra suffixes. You can either surround exported functions with `extern "C" { /*your code*/ }` block to prevent name mangling or write a module exports file (.def) with proper naming.

Comment: In the header or in the cpp? Can you please write an example?

Comment: In both header and cpp.

Comment: If I do it in the header it seems to work, but if I then do it in the cpp it doesn't

Comment: Oh, right, .cpp file does include the header with declaration that is already marked as extern, so there should be no need to wrap definition in .cpp with extern.